# Memory leakage in zmq client in c

Tags: c, zeromq

Memory Leakage in zmq client running using valgrind
Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<zmq.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <signal.h>
volatile sig_atomic_t stop;
void inthand(int signum) {
    stop = 1;
}
int main(){
        signal(SIGINT, inthand);
        char buffer[1024];
        int i=0;
        void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
        void *request = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
        zmq_connect(request,"tcp://10.30.11.215:2424");
        while(!stop){
                memset(buffer,0,1024);
                zmq_send(request,"HELLO",5,0);
                zmq_recv(request,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
        }
        zmq_close(request);
        zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
}
```

valgrind log:

```
==19532== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19532==     in use at exit: 36,678 bytes in 43 blocks
==19532==   total heap usage: 236 allocs, 193 frees, 138,270 bytes allocated
==19532== 
==19532== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19532==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19532==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19532==      possibly lost: 36,318 bytes in 38 blocks
==19532==    still reachable: 360 bytes in 5 blocks
==19532==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19532== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

why possibly lost leakage occur while running? Please help to solve the same.

Comment: `==19532== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory`

Comment: Do you have a record of how many iterations were made before the program stopped?  Was it 38 cycles?  Or perhaps 19 cycles?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now i run the same code for 50 iterations but no memory leakage is seen (All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible). I have no idea why code behaves indifferently. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Something changed, then.  Is the other end still running?  What diagnostics have you added to print the data that is received?  Do you still get the leak if you run without the `--leak-check=full` option?

Comment: Since you are on *nix, maybe try dumping [mallinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) after every iteration.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Other end runs continuously. While i am running the code with and without  --leak-check=full sometimes it shows leakage sometimes not. I put printf to check the data is received or not.

Comment: Always, indeed **always**, report the ØMQ library version, using **`zmq_version( &major, &minor, &patch );`** as both the versions' behaviour and maturity differ a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### Old and good ZeroMQ practice was carefull wrt resources:

A due care was expected to handle messages ( and hidden data-structures ):

```
zmq_msg_t            aMessage;
zmq_msg_init_size ( &aMessage,  1024 );
zmq_msg_data      ( &aMessage, "HELLO", 5 );
...
zmq_msg_close     ( &aMessage );
```

ought take place to "behave well".

### Why? Just read the API-specification with due care:

If non-compliant use-cases are compiled, the leaks were explicitly warned about in:

> The `zmq_msg_init_data()` function shall initialise the message object referenced by `msg` to represent the content referenced by the `buffer` located at address data, `size` bytes long. No copy of data shall be performed and ØMQ shall take ownership of the supplied buffer.
>
> If provided, the deallocation function `ffn` shall be called once the data buffer is no longer required by ØMQ, with the data and hint arguments supplied to `zmq_msg_init_data()`.
>
> Never access `zmq_msg_t` members directly, instead always use the `zmq_msg` family of functions.
>
> The deallocation function **`ffn`** needs to be thread-safe, since it will be called from an arbitrary thread.
>
> **If the deallocation function is not provided**, the **allocated memory will not be freed**, and **this may cause a memory leak.**